# Trying to write and compare text file with scraped text, not quite working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a program that pulls html from webpages and then compares it to previously scraped data that I have saved. If something has changed, it saves the new html to the text file and emails me. The problem is that it either writes text to the text files sporadically or not at all, and then will also email me randomly even if nothing has changed. I've been playing with it for 2 weeks and can't seem to figure out what's going on. Help!

```
import requests
import smtplib
import bs4
import os

abbvs = ['MCL', 'PFL', 'OPPL', 'FCPL', 'AnyPL', 'NOLS', 'VanWaPL', 'SLCPL', 'ProPL', 'ArapPL']
openurls = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/urls', 'r')
urls = openurls.read().strip('\n').split(',')
olddocs = ['oldMCL', 'oldPFL', 'oldOPPL', 'oldFCPL', 'oldAnyPL', 'oldNOLS', 'oldVanWaPL', 'oldSLCPL', 'oldProPL', 'oldArapPL']
newdocs = ['newMCL', 'newPFL', 'newOPPL', 'newFCPL', 'newAnyPL', 'newNOLS', 'newVanWaPL', 'newSLCPL', 'newProPL', 'newArapPL']
bstags = ['#content', '.col-md-12', '#main', '#containedInVSplit', '.col-sm-7', '.statement-left-div', '#main', '#main', '#componentBox', '.list-group.job-listings']

for url in urls: 
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
for bstag in bstags:
    currentsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    newsoup = currentsoup.select(bstag)
for newdoc in newdocs:
    if os.path.isfile('/home/ian/Pythonprograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+newdoc) == False:
        createnew = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+newdoc, 'w')

    file = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+newdoc, 'w')
    file.write(str(newsoup)) 
    file.close()

    new = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+newdoc)
    new = new.read()
for olddoc in olddocs:
    if os.path.isfile('/home/ian/Pythonprograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+olddoc) == False:
        createold = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+olddoc, 'w')

    old = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+olddoc)
    old = old.read()

if str(old) != str(new):
   file = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+olddoc, 'w') 
    file.write(str(new))
    file.close()

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('dummyemail', 'password')
    server.sendmail('noreply.job.updates.com', 'myemail', 'Subject: A library\'s jobs page has changed\n' '\n' + 'Here\'s the URL:' + str(url))
    server.quit()
elif str(old) == str(new):
    pass
```

Comment: Are the `abbvs` list one-to-one mapped to the `urls` and the `bstags` lists?

Comment: Yep! The `abbvs` list was originally part of trying something different so it's not actually used in the current code, but all of the lists have the `urls`, `docs`, and `bstags` in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. The main problem is that each loop is running to completion, leaving you with effectively only checking the last site. You need to run the comparisons for each set of `abbv`, `url` and `bstag`. For this there is a nice Python function called `zip()` that is good to understand.

In addition, you do not need to store the newly scraped data, as it can be compared directly to the old (and then only updated, if it is changed). With these changes, your code might look something like:

```
import requests
import smtplib
import bs4
import os

abbvs = ['MCL', 'PFL', 'OPPL', 'FCPL', 'AnyPL', 'NOLS', 'VanWaPL', 'SLCPL', 'ProPL', 'ArapPL']
openurls = open('/home/ian/PythonPrograms/job-scrape/urls', 'r')
urls = openurls.read().strip('\n').split(',')
bstags = ['#content', '.col-md-12', '#main', '#containedInVSplit', '.col-sm-7', '.statement-left-div', '#main', '#main', '#componentBox', '.list-group.job-listings']

for abbv, url, bstag in zip(abbvs, urls, bstags):
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    olddoc = 'old'+abbv
    currentsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    newsoup = str(currentsoup.select(bstag))

    filepath = '/home/ian/Pythonprograms/job-scrape/libsitehtml/'+olddoc
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as old:
            oldsoup = old.read()
    else:
        oldsoup = ''

    if newsoup != oldsoup:
        with open(filepath, 'w') as new:
            new.write(newsoup)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login('dummyemail', 'password')
        server.sendmail('noreply.job.updates.com', 'myemail', 'Subject: A library\'s jobs page has changed\n' '\n' + 'Here\'s the URL:' + str(url))
        server.quit()
```

I have not tested the above, though, so it may contain some error(s). But it should be something to start from. In addition, you should consider trying to make a `dict` with the `abbvs` as keys and the `urls` as values, as they are tightly connected.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I got stuck thinking about trying to do it one way and this makes so much more sense. And the dictionary idea is smart. Very very much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be emailing me each time now, seemingly regardless of if anything's changed. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems to indicate that there is some difference between `newsoup` and `oldsoup`. Is it happening for each website or for only one or a few of them?

Comment: It seems to only be happening on three of them. `PFL`, `VanWaPL`, and `FCPL`

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I think I figured out the problem. I'm pulling too much from the sites including things that change each session.